# Duplicate Id entry when a few users try to insert information into database - Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates, primary-key

When a few users try to insert a row into the table, this error appears:

(`325` is the ID of the row. there is no auto increasment because I'm doing it myself because I need it.)

[image: error]

I remember that in asp they have the `lock()` method that actually prevents this kind of errors.

Is there something similiar in PHP?

Code will be added if asked although I dont think its required.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you check for the last entry id and use it for the insert query, it will fail if another process is started before the first is actually ended. This is because both process will have same id, I think you should use auto increment field and retrieve last entry id after insert to use if you need

Comment: @Fabio I know that. My question is how can I solve it without enabling AUTO INCREASMENT.

Comment: As i told you just insert a row and then retrieve last entry id to use wherever you you need

Comment: This is exactly what Im doing, the problem is that when multipule users insert rows, collusions are happening. @Fabio

Comment: Just perform an insert query with the new id at the beginning of the process and update all data later. In this way if a second process starts before first is ended you won't have problem with duplicate ids

Comment: do not create unique id until the data submitted, at that time, you can get new ID and then insert, I think in this period duplicates might not occur.

Answer (score 1):

Now you see why you shouldn't assign IDs manually :)

Change your table to start assigning IDs automatically:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT=last_assigned_id+1
```

If you insist on implementing a lock, you can use [**sem_acquire**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sem-acquire.php)

Comment: Ty, can you give me an example of how to use it? what is `resource $sem_identifier`?

Comment: You can see a good example in the [*following question*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4857240/1057429)

Comment: Wait, but if i'll use it, will some of the users that submit the data at the same time get an error? I mean, does this lock everything for everyone exept for the first user?

Comment: @NirPes No, they'll get "locked" until the current user is done and only when the lock is released the next user will be allowed to "insert". You shouldn't worry unless you think that there's a good chance of many users performing the exact same action (insert) at the same time.

Comment: I do want to make sure that the proccess wont take too much time for the last user if lets say 1000 users submit their data. is it good to use in that case? @alfasin

Comment: Even preforming 1000 inserts shouldn't take more than a few seconds. I wouldn't worry about it unless your traffic (and form submitting in specific) is really big. that said, I don't like this solution and still think that using `AUTO_INCREMENT` is better.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37776/discussion-between-nirpes-and-alfasin)